# Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: childOne)

Tags: angularjs

**As a follow-up still regarding this plunker:**

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SakSg6x5wuQQ5eYBwFN?p=preview)**

**If I review the console in Chrome when selecting an item in Child 1, I get the following error:**

Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: childOne)

I am completely baffled as the directive element is an element, not an attribute and designated as such in the directive itself.

Answer (score 22):

**TL;DR;** - The problem is that attributes are **snake-case** and the scope definition transforms them to **camelCase**.

Well you have:

```
app.directive('childOne', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            labelName: "@",
            selectPhrase: "@",
            ngModel: "=",
            options: "=",
        },
        template: '<span><div class="local-label">{{labelName}}: </div><div style="width:15px;display:inline-block;"></div>' +
                  '<span style="display: inline-block;"><select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="o.Id as o.Name for o in options | orderBy:\'Name\'" class="formRequire" required><option value="" selected="selected">{{selectPhrase}} ...</option></select>' +
                  '</span></div></span>'
    };
})
```

The problem is that you bind ngModel but the child-one element doesn't provide a value for it. If I comment that part it seems to work ok.

It seems that when you have **"="** bindings in the scope it means mandatory, also attributes are transformed from **snake-case** to **camelCase** when defined in javascript world

*PS: It's true the error is a little vague*

Comment: Thanks Liviu, I really should not have used that plunker because I did not create it so I could not edit it. I changed the plunker so I could show the correction.

Comment: Thank you man for notice about camelCase transformations. in my case  name of attribute with underscore was the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this so it is not un-assignable?

Comment: @ajbraus the fix is by providing the value to the directive, = bindings are 2 way so the reference must be passed to the directive so that angular can update the value

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about camelCase vs. snake-case. That's annoying but an easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

```
<child-one 
      label-name="Child 1" select-phrase="Please Select Clutch Type" 
      selectModel="ClutchType.Id" options="clutchTypes" >
</child-one> 


selectModel="ClutchType.Id"
```

**should have been**

```
select-model="ClutchType.Id"
```